# remover o primeiro e ultimo caractere de uma string em C

Tags: c

preciso fazer um codigo onde eu preciso transformar uma string em um int, mas o usuario pode digitar o numero assim: **[1234]**, então eu preciso remover o primeiro e o ultimo caractere para assim ser possivel transformar a string em int. alguem pode me ajudar? já tentei fazer de varias formas, mas nada da certo

Comment: Uma possibilidade é utilizar a função `sscanf` para ler uma string `x` e ignorar o primeiro e último caracteres desta string e ler o inteiro entre eles: `sscanf(x, "%*c%d%*c", &n);`.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o atoi conforme a resposta do Natan.

Esse trecho ((char str[10] = "Teste321!")) não funcionou aqui comigo então fiz um for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char string[10], string_sem_colchete;
    gets(string);

    int numero, i;

    for(i=1; i<strlen(string)-1; i++){
       string_sem_colchete[i-1] = string[i];
    }

    string_sem_colchete[i-1] = '\0';
    numero = atoi(string_sem_colchete);

    printf("Meu numero eh: %d", numero);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode usar a função `atoi()` da biblioteca `stdlib.h`. Essa função pega os números da string e transforma em inteiro.
Exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[10] = "123";
    int x = atoi(str);
    printf("%d \n", x);

    char str2[10] = "Teste";
    x = atoi(str2);
    printf("%d \n", x);

    char str3[10] = "Teste321!";
    x = atoi(str3);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
123
0
321
```